# <img> element with onclick submits the form instead of firing action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having a weird issue in my Login.cshmtl view which I posted below. So on the top right corner of my login page, I have two textboxes for credentials and two .png images as their labels, a "Remember Me" checkbox and a .png image as its label, and finally a "ForgotPassword" .png image defined as:

```
<img onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")'" src="~/Content/Images/ForgotPassword.png" />
```

Everything worked fine until I changed this line as follows:

```
<input type="image" onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")'" src="~/Content/Images/ForgotPassword.png" />
```

Surprisingly, now my image-button is broken and it submits the page! Using the debugger I observe that POST method of my Login action is called instead of ForgotPassword action. Can you please explain how this happens? Below, I am posting the Login.cshtml view with irrelevant parts removed.

```
@model FooProject.Web.ViewModels.LoginViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    ....
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <input type="image" class="navbar-brand" onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'" src="~/Content/Images/logo.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin:10px">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <span class="actionLink">
                                    <img src="~/Content/Images/Username.png"/>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <span class="actionLink">
                                    <img src="~/Content/Images/Password.png"/> 
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm", @class = "navbar-right form-inline" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "" })
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) <br />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-left:0">
                                    <input type="image" alt="Submit" src="~/Content/Images/Login.png" style="width:45px" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                    <span class="actionLink">
                                        <img src="~/Content/Images/RememberMe.png" style="height:11px;vertical-align:top;margin-top:2px" />
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <img onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")'" src="~/Content/Images/ForgotPassword.png" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<input type="image">` works as submit button, so this is expected behavior.

But there is **solution**:

`<input type="image" onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")'; return false;" src="~/Content/Images/ForgotPassword.png" />` will do the trick.

By adding `return false;` you prevent submission from being executed.

There is also **alternative solution**:

There is no reason to replace `img` tag with `input`. If you want to see cursor on hover, you can do it with CSS:

```
img.submit:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and decorate img with `submit` class:

```
<img class="submit" onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")'" src="~/Content/Images/ForgotPassword.png" />
```

And the way **I would do that**:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")'>
    <img src="/Content/Images/ForgotPassword.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: My intention was indeed to see the cursor :) Thanks a lot for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

By changing the image tag to an input tag you've create an image as a submit button and it's doing what you should expect: submitting the form with the action and method defined.

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp for more information

Answer (score 1):

[From the W3C Wiki (emphasis is mine):](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/image)

> The image button state represents either an image from which a user
>   can select a coordinate and submit the form, or alternatively a button
>   from which the user can submit the form. **The element is a button,
>   specifically a submit button**